# Perforce Trigger to trigger when users attempt to Delete or Reparent Streams

Tags: triggers, perforce, perforce-stream

I am trying to create safeguards for users to prevent them from accidentally deleting or re-parenting streams

- re-parenting is easily accidentally done when attempting to drag workspaces between streams.
- deleting is sometimes accidentally clicked when right clicking on streams to go to 'Edit Stream'.

We use a lot of triggers already to help users and I was wondering if either/both of these situations can be solved with a preventative trigger?

Through initial research I can't find a trigger which is triggered by either of these situations. Does anyone know if any of these triggers can be made to trigger from stream deletes or re-parents:
https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/triggers.html

If not, are there any other methods in Perforce that can be used to help users with these issues?

Comment: The triggers of type 'command' can be used here, perhaps? (1) Figure out which underlying p4 commands are getting run by p4v by using the p4v log window, (2) use the command type triggers for those commands: https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4sag/Content/P4SAG/scripting.triggers.order.html This is pretty advanced stuff, but you noted in your question you're a pretty advanced site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form triggers should fire when you modify streams, since streams are forms.  Making a `form-delete` trigger that returns a failure code will prevent users from deleting streams, and you can add a `form-save` trigger that checks to make sure that a change to a stream doesn't include changing the parent.